# cross browser & cross platform video in web page without flash

Tags: video, cross-browser, cross-platform, video-streaming

I have a .mov video file and need to view it in a web page. It must be viewed on Windows, Mac, iPhone and this list of browsers: IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari.
I could use HTML5, but then it wont be viewable in IE less than version 9 :(
How could it be solved without flash?
PS. the viewed video file can be another format too, not mov only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want is not simple. What audio/video codecs are in your QuickTime (.mov) file? To reach all major platforms and browsers without Flash, you'll need to encode the file multiple times (and should still use Flash as a fallback for old browsers). A good introduction to cross-platform video playback is:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html

To summarize what it says, the main video/audio codec options are VP8 + Vorbis, H.264 baseline + AAC and Theora + Vorbis. Unfortunately, if you want to reach all recent versions of all major browsers, you'll have to provide the file encoded in all three of these formats (you can list multiple version in an HTML5  tag). If you're willing to use Flash, you can reduce that to a single H.264 baseline + AAC file (in .mp4 container) played by Flash everywhere but on the iPhone, where it would play in a  tag.

Sorry for not giving a simple answer, but it's complicated. FFmpeg is the tool to use to re-encode your file into these different formats.

Comment: Yes than You for answer I found some solutions, they involve to have at least 3 different video formats, just as You wrote. even if these solutions should work on ipad or iphone they don't. it's realy complicated...

Answer (score 1):

welcome in the unstandardized world of video (at least before html5) :)

To be more constructive, I think you will end up in setting a matrix which defines for each browser version and for each video format the correct html output to display properly the video.

If you can, rely on HTML5 features, and if you want to support IE <= V8, put the correct object plugin, which can be :

- Flash (most installed)
- SilverLigth player
- QuickTime Player
- VLC plugin
- Media player activex
- ...

... or welcome IE <=8 users with a message telling them IE9 is great. You'll make MS guy happy